# Linearly independent set in field of rational functions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, rational-functions

Here is a problem I'm working on:

Show that the set of rational functions $P = \{\frac{1}{x-a} : a \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly independent set in the field of rational functions $\mathbb{Q}(x)$.

First, the wording is throwing me off. Does the above amount to showing that $a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 + ... + a_nv_n = 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $a_1 = a_2 = ... = a_n = 0$ for $v_1,v_2,...,v_n \in P$ and $a_1,a_2,...,a_n \in \mathbb{Q}$ ?

In other words, we need to show that **$a_1\frac{1}{x-q_1} + a_2\frac{1}{x-q_2} + ... + a_n\frac{1}{x-q_n} = 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $a_1 = a_2 = ... = a_n$ for some $a_1, a_2, ... , a_n \in \mathbb{Q}$ and rational numbers $q_1, q_2, ... , q_n$, right?

If that's the case, I suppose I haven't been able to see the trick yet as to how equation ** forces the scalars $a_i$ to be all zero. How can I show this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have understood what the question is asking you to do.

As for how to solve it, consider the following: Start with a linear combination
$$
a_1\frac1{x-q_1} + a_2\frac1{x-q_2} + \cdots a_n\frac1{x-q_n} = 0
$$
for rational $a_i$ and rational $q_i$, with all the $q_i$ are distinct (if any of them are equal, we can just put them together in a single term, adding together their respective $a_i$'s). From here, we can multiply on the left and on the right by $(x-q_1)(x-q_2)\cdots(x-q_n)$. This gives us
$$
a_1(x-q_2)(x-q_3)\cdots(x-q_n) + a_2(x-q_1)(x-q_3)\cdots(x-q_n)+\\
 \cdots + a_n(x-q_1)(x-q_2)\cdots(x-q_{n-1}) = 0
$$
Now insert $x = q_1$ in the above expression. What do you get (remember our assumption that all the $q_i$ are distinct)? What about if you insert $x = q_2$? Keep going, inserting all the different $q_i$ for $x$, and this problem is solved.

Comment: Why you can insert $x=q_i$ if we get the linear combination of $\frac{1}{x-q_i}$; in particular, we can't get $x=q_i$ because you'll divide by zero.

Comment: @jpatrick No, because we are not inserting $x=q_i$ in the original equality with fractions. We have multiplied away all those denominators to get the second equality. That is an equality of polynomials, and as such the two sides must in particular evaluate to equal no matter what we insert for $x$. Even for $x=q_i$, where the original equality doesn't have a valid evaluation.

Comment: But if you get the domain of function being the linear combination you have to omit $q_i,$ so then you don't have $q_i$ all time in the domain. Maybe I'm missing something... I think more formally safe is to say that in numerator one has polynomial function and from equality of linear independence we conlude that this polynomial function has infinite number of roots (we have this polynomial function under inifnite field $\mathbb{R}$), so this polynomial function has to be determined by zero polynomial, hence the assertion follows.

Comment: @jpatrick But polynomials **aren't functions**. And neither are rational functions, despite their name. They are more abstract objects in their own right, and you can multiply and divide them following the standard rules of algebra. There is a notion of evaluation, but that doesn't make them into functions. And if you take an equality of rational functions and multiply away the denominators, you get an equality of polynomials. And if you have an equality of polynomials, regardless of how that equality came to be, you get an equality for each and every possible evaluation.

Comment: Yeah, I perfectly know it. That's why I say polynomial function determined by polynomial. I know that polynomial and polynomial function are different notion. Though, I thought that $K(x)\subset F(K,K).$ But for polynomial you can't evaluate at $q_i$ because $x$ is formal indeterminate. Getting $x=q_i$ you make polynomial into polynomial function.

Comment: @jpatrick In that case I really can't understand your issue here. Do you disagree that $$a_1\frac1{x-q_1} + a_2\frac1{x-q_2} + \cdots a_n\frac1{x-q_n}
 $$ being the zero rational function implies that $$a_1(x-q_2)(x-q_3)\cdots(x-q_n) + a_2(x-q_1)(x-q_3)\cdots(x-q_n)+\\
 \cdots + a_n(x-q_1)(x-q_2)\cdots(x-q_{n-1}) $$is the zero polynomial? Or do you disagree that we can evaluate the above polynomial at $x=q_i$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116899/discussion-between-jpatrick-and-arthur).

Comment: @jpatrick I do not like to discuss in chat. It creates an expectation that I should be more readily available than does the comment section. It is more difficult to find when I get out of bed tomorrow morning and decide to check whether you've replied. And also, I don't get pings when you respond over there. Let's stay here. It is better.

Comment: I disagree that we can evaluate. I think about these notions too formally, maybe. But if polynomial isn't function I can't evaluate because x is formal indeterminate. I think we should to check when the coefficients of polynomial in nominator are equal 0. It led unfortunately to very bad computations. But I suggest that we can identify polynomial with polynomial functions because of the infinity of field, and in this setting we can evaluate. But I am not sure if we can take $x=q_i$ because of domain.

Comment: @jpatrick Polynomials aren't functions, but there is still a notion of evaluation. In other words, each polynomial defines a polynomial function, and this function's domain is all of $\Bbb Q$ (we never divide by anything with $x$ in it during this evaluation, after all). Each $q_i$ is a rational number, and therefore a valid place to evaluate the polynomial function.

Comment: You're right generally but here we have a step earlier rational functions where $q_i$ can't be an argument of rational function $\frac{1}{x-q_i}$. If I understood, you have told that it doesn't matter under evaluation in the numerator, right?

Comment: @jpatrick The rational function cannot be evaluated at $q_i$. The polynomial can. It doesn't matter that the polynomial comes from a rational function where you can't.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you at all, I see it. Thanks.